# Does complete graph $G$ have an independence number $\alpha(G) =1$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I am in a little confusion, so here is my reasoining. For a complete graph with 5 verticies $ K_{5}, \text{ indpendent set I = } \{\varnothing,\{1\},…,\{5\}\},$  which means that independence number $\alpha(G) =|\{1\}| =1?$  But for me intuitively a complete graph has $\alpha(G)=0$ since there is NO such set on $K_{5}$ where no verticies are adjacent. Any good suggestion to clarify my confusion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, a complete graph has independence number $\alpha(G)=1$.

Note that an independent set $S$ of size one is the largest set of vertices you can choose without an edge between any two vertices in the set. A set without at least two vertices results in the property being vacuously true. Pick any two distinct vertices in the set $S$ - you can't, there's only one - therefore the property is satisfied. Note that it doesn't matter that the vertex in $S$ has neighbours outside of $S$ - it only matters that there are no two vertices, both in $S$, with an edge between them in the graph.